# Append values to beginning and end of every other line in ndjson file with Python or jq

Tags: json

I have a ndjson file with first several lines as such:

```
{"index":{}}
{"data":"John Doe","edType":"FG"}
{"index":{}}
{"data":"Jane Doe","edType":"GG"}
{"index":{}}
{"data":"Jim Doe","edType":"FG"}
```

Using Python (I'm on 3.10) I need to append additional data to beginning and end of each line that it not an `index` line.  The result would look like this:

```
{"index":{}}
{"name":{"data":"John Doe","edType":"FG"}}
{"index":{}}
{"name":{"data":"Jane Doe","edType":"GG"}}
{"index":{}}
{"name":{"data":"Jim Doe","edType":"FG"}}
```

I've tried this using several suggestions here which seem to only apply to text files.  I am wondering if I have to do this with the JSON module or not.

Alternatively, if easier to attain in jq, I'm happy to use that too.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to do this in Python? It would be a one-liner in jq.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm actually happy to do it in jq!  Can you share the syntax?

Comment: `jq -c '., {"name": input}' <in.jsonl >out.jsonl` ("ndjson" is a new one for me; I'm accustomed to this format being described as "jsonl", as described at https://jsonlines.org/).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that did it!  Looks like I need to learn jq syntax - so much easier.

Comment: If you change the tagging to not be specifically a python question, I'd be glad to add that as an answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trivially done with `jq`:

```
jq -c '., {"name": input}'
```

- `-c` specifies compact output, so we have one output line per JSON value (matching the input format)
- `.` refers to the current input item
- `input` retrieves the *next* input item (consuming it, so it's no longer eligible to become `.`)

...and the sequence repeats as long as more inputs are available.

Comment: oh that's slick